Does offering contract-based work help my overall application?
This is a general question, so please bear with me.
A Fortune 500 company has an IT position for a full-time employee. This company has a history of hiring full-time employees as well as doing contract-based work. After several rounds of interviews, they have two candidates, and I'm one of them.
Considering the fact that many people (if not most) prefer being an employee for the benefits (healthcare, vacation/sick time, etc.) and the "job security", would it help my cause if I suggest to the talent planner that I can start with contract-based work?
The main benefit for the company is that they can simply terminate my contract and that would be it. Terminating an employee is much more difficult.
Generally speaking, do companies prefer hiring employees or hiring contractors?

Deleting your previous question just to ask the same exact one is not going to help you here. This is still not on topic for this site, neither your actual question (the title) or the one you threw in at the end. Total strangers on the internet cannot tell you if some unnamed company will be more likely to hire you as a contractor.

It's pretty bleak to consider the main benefit of hiring you is to be able to kick you out easily. Why do you think it is necessary to undersell yourself so drastically?

@MisterMiyagi: the question was intended as a way that the company might see benefit out of the transition. Then again, if that's the conclusion you reached from my question, then I applaud you for it.

@JimScott What transition?

The transition of going from a contractor to an employee.

Terminating an employee is much more difficult - How so? In the vast majority of cases, it's as easy as saying "Your employment has been terminated."

Probably not.

Fortune 500 companies have a list of approved vendors.  Getting a new vendor approved requires multiple feet worth of paperwork.  In order to hire you as a contractor, you'd need to go through the process of getting your company added as an approved vendor.  That would require that you establish a company, it probably requires that your company purchase E&O insurance, etc.  That would be a vast amount of effort if they were only going to have you do a 6 month contract and then hire you.

They already (presumably) have budget allocated for an employee.  Contractors would be paid out of a different budget.  Having you start as a contractor and then hiring you requires a lot of manipulation of the budget.  It may require getting the new hire budget re-authorized when they want to transition you which is never a guarantee.

Although no one is going to ding your application for being flexible, it is pretty easy to come across as desperate in making such an offer.  If there are two solid candidates at the end and one projected confidence that she'd do a great job and the other seemed a bit desperate and was already thinking about what would be the easiest way to part ways, it is likely that the confident candidate will get the offer.

Contractors and employees are not supposed to be interchangeable.  Based on the job you're doing, the IRS has rules about whether you should be classified as an employee or not.  As with any law, there are grey areas but Fortune 500 companies are going to be rather conscious of not doing things that would lead to lawsuits about improperly categorizing employees as contractors.  An employee slot that got converted to a contractor doing exactly the same job and then converted back to an employee would cause a great deal of consternation in the HR/ legal department because it would be Exhibit A if they were ever sued.



Thanks so much for the answer. You're right: I worked as a contractor for healthcare and they never paid me directly; it was through a 3rd-party approved vendor.

No, it would not help your application. It would actually hinder it, by demonstrating that you are confused. When organisations hire an employee, they're seeking someone to become part of the organisation, preferably for a long time. Both parties make commitments as part of that process.
A contract role, by comparison, is for a defined task and is temporary. The relationship is completely different.

When companies are hiring contractors, they are hiring contractors.
When companies are hiring employees, they are hiring employees.
Confusing the two is not likely to help you.

@IvovanderVeeken that isn't typically how Fortune 500 companies work. Maybe it should be, but it's not.
